# Angular Modal Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, cloud9-ide

I'm trying to get modals working in my Angular application. I tried using Bootstrap and Angular Material modals but I could not make them work. I decided to try with Angular Modal Service, however I'm getting the same error. Whenever I call the function ModalService.showModal I get the following error:

```
angular.js:12416 TypeError: Cannot read property 'showModal' of undefined
at Scope.$scope.show (AboutController.js:4)
at fn (eval at <anonymous> (angular.js:13231), <anonymous>:4:203)
at callback (angular.js:23371)
at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15878)
at Scope.$apply (angular.js:15978)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:23376)
at HTMLAnchorElement.n.event.dispatch (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jquery-2.2.3.min.js:3)
```

**The service im using:**

```
https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service
```

**The JS Fiddle example that I used:**

```
http://jsfiddle.net/dwmkerr/8MVLJ/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=8MVLJ
```

**Include:**

```
<!-- Include jQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include Bootstrap -->
<script src="../node_modules/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- Include Angular -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.js"></script>
<!-- Include ModalService-->
<script src="../node_modules/angular-modal-service/dst/angular-modal-service.min.js"></script>
```

**About.html:**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 form-box">

<h3>Comentarios</h3>

<a class="btn btn-default" href ng-click="show()">Show a Modal</a>
 <!-- The actual modal template, just a bit o bootstrap -->
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
     <div class="modal fade">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close('Cancel')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Yes or No?</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>It's your call...</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" ng-click="close('No')" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>
            <button type="button" ng-click="close('Yes')" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </script>
</div>
</div>
```

**App.module.js:**

```
var Tiendiia = angular.module('Tiendiia', ['ui.router', 'ngMaterial', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies', 'angularModalService',]);

Tiendiia.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
$mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
.primaryPalette('yellow')
.accentPalette('orange')
.warnPalette('amber')
.backgroundPalette('grey');
});
```

**AboutController.js**

```
Tiendiia.controller('AboutController', ['$scope',  function($scope, ModalService) {

$scope.show = function() {
    ModalService.showModal({
        templateUrl: 'modal.html',
        controller: "ModalController"
    }).then(function(modal) {
        modal.element.modal();
        modal.close.then(function(result) {
            $scope.message = "You said " + result;
        });
    });
};


}]);
```

**ModalController.js**

```
Tiendiia.controller('ModalController', function($scope, close) {

 $scope.close = function(result) {
close(result, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
};

});
```

I have looked everywhere I could, but I can't find why it's not working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On angular material it is called dialog what you need. Sometimes angular material uses John Papa style that is recommended but sometimes difficult to understand for beginners. If you understand this guide then you really understand angular.

[Link To styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

Try to use modal of ui.bootstrap and do not add unnecessary libraries with functionality that you already have on ui bootstrap. Anyways I think your error might be here:

It seems that on **about controller**

`['$scope',  function($scope, ModalService)`

you need to add ModalService

`['$scope', 'ModalService',  function($scope, ModalService)`

Comment: Beat me to it. I believe that you are correct. The reason for this is because he has to include his `ModalService` as a dependency injection for the controller.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Thats the right answer, I had tried that previously but gave me an error I guess it was fixed when I added the bootstrap.js. Would you mind to elaborate a bit more why I need to include the dependency in the controller and not just on the function?

Comment: Angular uses dependency injection. So for example you downloaded ui.boostrap. And you need to say to your app:hey I need that library, so you inject the module. The same when a controller needs a service and others.  It is like an import. Angular actually will inject to your controller without the array like you do on ModalController.js. The problem with that is that if you use uglify it will change to letters. so it will transform to Tiendiia.controller('ModalController', function(a, b) {..}. So how you said that a is $scope? You pass the string with an array on the same order.

Comment: Check this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector and also have a look to the dependency injection pattern in general and on angular...

Comment: I think part of the reason this question is confusing is that the examples on the Angular Modal Service project github page (https://github.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service) don't include the 'ModalService' dependency in the controller dependencies.